# OpenCV Detect specific square and extract text

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract text from a specific square in multiple images using python.I have attached some examples of the images below.

This image does not provide the expected outcome
[image]
[image: Output from image 1]

This image does provide the expected outcome, however it provides it twice.
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
image_number = 0

os.listdir(f)
for file in os.listdir(f):
    f_img = f+"/"+file
    image = cv2.imread(f_img)
    
    # Grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find Canny edges
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

    # Finding Contours
    # Use a copy of the image e.g. edged.copy()
    # since findContours alters the image
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, 
        cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)



    print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours)))

    # Draw all contours
    # -1 signifies drawing all contours
    cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    for c in contours:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        if h > 30:
           
            if w > 100:
                if w < 500:
                    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
                    #---format is height y to y +h and width x to x+w
                    roi = image[y: y+h, x:x+w]

                    cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(image_number), roi)
                    image_number += 1
```

Currently, my code sometimes extracts the correct boxes but also other unneeded boxes. Below are the current images.

Comment: Your question is off to a good start. I like that you have code and have given a sample picture. Probably you need to add some more pictures that show what you're looking for. For the sample picture you provided, is your code working as you expect? You may need to provide one working picture and one non-working picture.

Comment: Thank you for the idea @bfris. Currently none of them work so I have provided the current outputs. If I get it working I will post an update.

Comment: Updated the post with a working image, i really cannot work out why the program works for some images but not others.

Comment: You could try running ocr to get location of `TCB` or `Signaling & Remarks` then do a crop with its padded location to right side of image and to certain amount toward bottom. This way the crop should have only one 4 sided polygon. Now it should be possible to get that rectangle and extract the texts only inside.

Comment: If the "TCB" rectangle is always in the same place in the image, you could crop the image and then do OCR.